# WTC2021 Iterators Paclet download

Tags: iterators, paclets

At WTC2021 Roman Maeder gave a presentation about [Iterators](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?v=3542).
In the presentation [notebook](https://files.wolframcdn.com/pub/www.wolfram.com/technology-conference/2021/Iterators.nb) it is mentioned that the code / paclet (**Iterators-0.9.paclet**) is provided as part of the presentation resources with a screenshot how to get it.

Unfortunately it seems that it is only possible to access the presentation resources if you attended WTC2021. So my question is if anyone has access to the mentioned paclet and can provide a download link?

Comment: The paclet is [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/rohit.namjoshi/Iterators-0.9.paclet) and the presentation notebook is [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/rohit.namjoshi/Iterators-Maeder-Draft.nb).

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I meant. If you post it as an answer I can accept it. By the way: the presentation notebooks are available now at the WTC2021 (https://www.wolfram.com/events/technology-conference/2021/presentations/) page but not with the additional resources.

Comment: Probably a good idea to [let them know](https://www.wolfram.com/contact-us/) about the missing resource so that they can correct it.